# nuxt js page with keycloak js authentication middleware reloaded twice when browser window refreshed?nuxtjs router not waiting until promises resolves

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, keycloak, nuxt.js

I am using keycloak for authentication with following code in nuxt js middleware:

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'

const keycloak = new Keycloak({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
  realm: 'dev-employee',
  clientId: 'emp-ui'
})

export default function({ store, redirect }) {
  if (keycloak.authenticated) return true

  return keycloak
    .init({
      onLoad: 'login-required',
      checkLoginIframe: true,
      checkLoginIframeInterval: 5
    })
    .success(authenticated => {})
    .error(function() {
      alert('failed to initialize')
    })
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
 router: {
    middleware: ['authentication']
  },
```

when the browser window loaded the page will render and authenticate and re-loads the page again. expected behavior page should not render until keycloak authentication successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return a new Promise in the middleware, something like this:

```js
export default function({ store, redirect }) {
  if (keycloak.authenticated) return true

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    keycloak
      .init({
        onLoad: 'login-required',
        checkLoginIframe: true,
        checkLoginIframeInterval: 5
      })
      .success(resolve)
      .error(reject)
  })
}
```

Comment: I did a test using a simple `setTimeout` and it worked great, thanks for the help